# Nuxt (Vue), resolve route after login, add beforeGuard on dynamically generated routes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, nuxt.js

As you know Nuxt automatically generates VueRouter with given pages. 
What I want to achieve is to add a custom auth guard.
So basically before rendering a route i check whether user is authenticated and if yes show the page, if not show login page and resolve the path after login.

So the docs point to middleware as a way to handle such cases. 
In my case my `auth.js` in `middleware` folder:

```
export default function (ctx) {
    const { store, redirect } = ctx
    if (!store.state.currentUser) {
        return redirect('/signin')
    }
}
```

That works fine for redirecting to the login/signup page. The problem is that i don't have a way to resolve original path after user signs in.

Something like:

```
onUserLoggedIn(){
    this.$router.next()
}
```

in ths `SignIn.vue` component

Do you have an idea how to solve this

Alternatively is there a way to set `beforeGuard` on dynamic routes generated by Nuxt?

Comment: Hi, the ctx contains the route, and on it should also be the params and query, also as full path, would this suffice?

Comment: Yep, I've considered that option - it should work well when in SSR as the context is passed through client and server afaik. I know it's a bit awkwardi since i only want to take the advantages of SSR in parts of my app (for SEO) and would rather have it behave like SPA in other parts (those that require user/profile management). It might sound strange but i'm using Firebase lib for auth() and database which is fairly simple to handle on client side and I really don't want to wast time implementing it on the backend

Answer (score 0):

Have you allready tried `router.go(n)`

Taken from the [Docs](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/navigation.html):

`This method takes a single integer as parameter that indicates by how many steps to go forwards or go backwards in the history stack, similar to window.history.go(n).`

The other method would be to `store` the path before redirect and reuse it later.